# Error while installing msi setup for window service develped in .net 2003

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2003

I am trying to install a windows service msi setup to one environment but I am facing the error, I have attached snap of the error here please do check and let me know the possibility to get it succeeded. [this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G41MO.jpg)

```
Error : unable to get installer in the f:\.... assembly;
one or more of the types in the assembly unable to load
```

Comment: Post the error text in the question, not as a linked picture. BTW, VS 2003 is worse than ancient - it supports only .NET 1.1 which is no longer used. All computers have .NET 2.0 at least and the earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2. You won't be able to run .NET 1.1. applications *or installers* that depend on it anywhere

Comment: So you mean that above error is due this only and there is no any other option to migrate the functionality to .Net 2.0

Comment: You didn't provide any logs, detailed errors or mention what was logged in the Event Viewer so I can only guess. It's 100% guaranteed though that you can't use an installer that uses .NET 1.1 action on a machine that doesn't have .NET 1.1